# How to add key name in nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array(5) {

    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2013-09-18"
        [1]=> string(75) "Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors"
        [2]=> string(74) "ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2010-10-20"
        [1]=> string(40) "Taking A Closer Look At Tech Conferences"
        [2]=> string(40) "taking-a-closer-look-at-tech-conferences"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2014-10-19"
        [1]=> string(29) "Wayfinding For The Mobile Web"
        [2]=> string(29) "wayfinding-for-the-mobile-web"
    }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2014-05-15"
        [1]=> string(24) "Freebie: Icons Of Autumn"
        [2]=> string(23) "freebie-icons-of-autumn"
    }

    [4]=> &array(1){
        [0]=> string(0) ""
    }
}
```

How would I go about assigning key names to each part of the inner array? E,g date, title, pathname.

I understand you can do something like this to create an array with certain keys, but how does this work with multiple nested arrays? And how can it be assigned after array creation?

```
$keys = array('Date', 'Title', 'Filepath');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$array1` is your main array (with 5 values).

```
foreach($array1 as $a)
{
     if (len($a) == 3)
          $array2[] = array("Date" => $a[0], "Title" => $a[1], "Filepath" => $a[2]);
}

$array1 = $array2;
```

Comment: Hi, this works but I get "Undefined offset: 1" and the same for [2] - what's causing that?

Comment: That's because `$array1[4]` is missing Title and Date.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I have no idea where array[4] is coming from, I think there is some whitespace at the end of the file it's reading from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach`.

```
$new = [];

foreach ($origArray as $inner) {
    $new[] = [
        "date" => $inner[0],
        "title" => $inner[1],
        "filepath" => $inner[2]
    ];
}

$origArray = $new;
```

This doesn't handle cases where the item does not conform to the "standard" (e.g item 4) but this should get you started.